# How to append nonEditableContent fixed on top and bottom of generated contentEditables div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, contenteditable

I am trying to "emulate" fixed and non-editable **headers** and **footers** on dynamically generated div with content editable = true.

First I've tried to put the header and footer using this css:

```
.header{
                /*margin:-100px 0px;*/
                margin-left: -2cm;
                background-color: red;
                vertical-align:middle; 
                text-align:center;
            }
            .footer{
                background-color: darkgray;
                margin-top: 735px;
                height: 100px;
                margin-left: -2cm;
            }
```

and tried to enable the header on the first page, worked fine:

```
<div id="editor">
            <div contenteditable="true" class="page" id="page-1">
                <div class="header" contenteditable="false">
                    <img class="brasao" alt="brasao-rj*" src="https://i.imgur.com/ktmBQCS.png" />
                    <span>Procuradoria Geral do Estado do Rio de Janeiro</span>
                </div>
                <b>hello</b>
                <div class="footer" contenteditable="false">
                    Rua Carmo do Cajuru 128
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But the footer not worked as expected because the user can push down the footer puting more content on the div.

In my current approach, I've tried to append the "header" div before call the newPage.focus(). But unfortunately, the behavior was not as expected, allowing the user to push down both, header and footer.

```
const getHeader = () => {
    let header = document.createElement('div');
    header.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
    header.setAttribute('class', 'header');
    let imgBrasao = document.createElement('img');
    imgBrasao.class = 'brasao';
    imgBrasao.setAttribute('class', 'brasao');
    imgBrasao.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/ktmBQCS.png';
    let spanPGE = document.createElement('span');
    spanPGE.textContent = 'Procuradoria Geral do Estado do Rio de Janeiro';
    header.appendChild(imgBrasao);
    header.appendChild(spanPGE);
    return header;
};    
const getFooter = () => {
    let footer = document.createElement('div');
    footer.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
    footer.setAttribute('class', 'footer');
    let spanPGE = document.createElement('span');
    spanPGE.textContent = 'Rua Carmo do Cajuru 128 - Centro RJ';
    footer.appendChild(spanPGE);
    return footer;
};
```

The full code is here:

https://jsitor.com/ETmvUUXaS

(the version without header and footer: https://jsitor.com/9J30B6YfG)

So, how can I emulate header and footers on those content editable divs?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you want to create multiple a4 sized pages with fixed header and footer on each page? Will each page be created when the editable div is overflowing in content? And will each page be clones from a html template?

Comment: First question: yes. Second question: without header and footer problem, my current code has this feature already working well. Third question: empty pages but with header and footer

Comment: The code does not seem to work seamlessly. I tried to add content but the `p` element kept expanding and a new page "was not" added. Is there a reason you are setting `contenteditable="true"` for the main div and not just `p` element?

Comment: the version without header and footer (working on firefox and chrome): https://jsitor.com/9J30B6YfG

Comment: Would you consider jQuery to resolve this?

Comment: Of course, no prejudice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it without jQuery. The concept is to add a wrapper around your content and add events to that wrapper instead of the page. Also, I created a template HTML page so the code can clone without performing cleanup.

To keep footer at the bottom I changed the page display to `flex` and the `flex-direction` to `column`. Then set `margin-top: auto` for footer.

Here is the code:

```js
function redator(divId) {
  const root = document.getElementById(divId)
  const a4 = {
    height: 830,
    width: 595,
    lineHeight: 30
  };
  const template = document.querySelector('#template');
  const headerHeight = root.querySelector('#page-1 .header').offsetHeight;
  const footerHeight = root.querySelector('#page-1 .footer').offsetHeight;

  const getChildrenHeight = (element) => {

    total = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element).paddingBottom);

    if (element.childNodes) {
      for (let child of element.childNodes) {
        switch (child.nodeType) {
          case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            total += child.offsetHeight;
            break;
          case Node.TEXT_NODE:
            let range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(child);
            rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
            total += (rect.bottom - rect.top);
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    return total;
  };

  const getPageHeight = (content) => {
    const children = getChildrenHeight(content);
    return children + headerHeight + footerHeight;

  };

  const setSelection = (node, offset) => {
    let range = document.createRange();
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(node, offset);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  };

  const addPage = () => {

    const newPage = template.cloneNode(true);
    const pages = root.getElementsByClassName('page');

    newPage.id = 'page-' + (pages.length + 1);
    newPage.className = 'page';
    root.appendChild(newPage);
    newPage.querySelector(".content").focus();
    newPage.querySelector(".content").addEventListener('input', onInput);

    newPage._emptyPage = true;
    return newPage.querySelector(".content");
  };

  function onInput(e) {
    const content = this;
    const page = this.closest(".page")
    const previousPage = page.previousElementSibling;
    const nextPage = page.nextElementSibling;

    const pageHeight = getPageHeight(content);
    const lastChild = content.lastChild;
    const cloneChild = lastChild.cloneNode(true);
    const textContent = content.innerText;
    if ((pageHeight === 0 || textContent.length <= 1) && !!previousPage && !page._emptyPage) {
      page.remove();
      previousPage.querySelector(".content").focus();
      const lastChild = previousPage.querySelector(".content").lastChild;
      setSelection(lastChild, lastChild.childNodes.length);
    } else if (pageHeight > a4.height && !nextPage) {
      lastChild.remove();
      addPage().appendChild(cloneChild);
    } else if (pageHeight > a4.height && nextPage) {

      lastChild.remove();
      nextPage.querySelector(".content").insertBefore(cloneChild, nextPage.querySelector(".content").firstChild);
      let selection = getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentElement.closest('div');
      if (selection === page.lastChild) {
        setSelection(cloneChild, 0);
      }
    } else if (pageHeight < a4.height - a4.lineHeight && !!nextPage) {
      let firstChildOfNextPage = nextPage.firstChild;
      let clone = firstChildOfNextPage.cloneNode(true);
      firstChildOfNextPage.remove();
      page.appendChild(clone);
    }
    page._emptyPage = false;
  }

  document.execCommand("DefaultParagraphSeparator", false, "div");
  root.querySelector('#page-1 .content').addEventListener('input', onInput);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  redator('editor');
}, false);
redator('editor');
```

```css
#editor {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px black;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

.page {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid black;
  /*padding: 10em 2em;*/
  width: 595px;
  height: 841px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  padding-left: 2cm;
  padding-bottom: 2cm;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  background-color: darkgray;
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.brasao {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

#template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>My Editor</h3>
<div id="editor">
  <div class="page" id="page-1">
    <div class="header">
      <img class="brasao" alt="brasao-rj*" src="https://i.imgur.com/ktmBQCS.png" />
      <span>Procuradoria Geral do Estado do Rio de Janeiro</span>
    </div>
    <div class='content' contenteditable="true">
      <b>hello</b>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      Rua Carmo do Cajuru 128
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="template">
  <div class="header">
    <img class="brasao" alt="brasao-rj*" src="https://i.imgur.com/ktmBQCS.png" />
    <span>Procuradoria Geral do Estado do Rio de Janeiro</span>
  </div>
  <div class='content' contenteditable="true">

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Rua Carmo do Cajuru 128
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very cool ! But do you know why appears this small line ? (blue on chrome and dotted on firefox)? https://i.imgur.com/2XPS2mx.png

Comment: Yes that's the [outline](http://www.outlinenone.com/) border. You can hide it by setting `outline: none`, although not recommended.

Comment: I will go with outline-color: white; Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if I increase the padding-top of .content, the footer is shrinked too?

Comment: Yes because I only factored in the padding-bottom. In `getChildrenHeight()` you can add this after the first line: `total += parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element).paddingTop);`

Answer (score 0):

Make only the `.body` element `contentEditable` and set it to false when it gets past a certain height:

```js
let bodyMHeight = $(".page").height() - $(".header").height() - $(".footer").height();

$(".body").on("input", function() {
   //console.log($(".body").height(), bodyMHeight);
   if($(".body").height() > bodyMHeight){
      //console.log("over");
      $(this).attr("contenteditable", "false");
   }else{
      //console.log("not over");
   }
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

.page{
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column;
   height: 100vh;
   min-height: 250px;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.header img {
   height: 100px;
}

.body{
  flex: 1;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.footer {
  background-color: darkgray;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor">
  <div class="page" id="page-1">
    <div class="header">
      <img class="brasao" alt="brasao-rj*" src="https://i.imgur.com/ktmBQCS.png" />
      <span>Procuradoria Geral do Estado do Rio de Janeiro</span>
    </div>
    <div class="body" contenteditable="true"> 
        <b>hello</b>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Rua Carmo do Cajuru 128
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but unfortunately this code is not considering the pre-existent code to emulate pages :(